# foreign keys and databases (laravel 6 from scratch episdoe 30)

Tags: laravel-6

Hi I need help with my learning I do the following code I that I am writing from laracast for some reason dont oupout foreign key value in my database Please help:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('excerpt');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could you elaborate? Definition looks good, what is the exact issue you are having? Maybe a format of: What do you expect and what is the actual result? What code are you running to fill this table?

Comment: Hi Rob Yes :) I am trying to learn laravel6 from scratch folowing laracast episode 30 and following everything he says and writes, when I use php artisan tinker and migrate all tables get populated with correct structer how ever the when i connect to my database (using local wamp) and to connect using table plus. The foreign key is not assigned with user_id so when I drop the user all articles will not delete. I meam problem I have looks like when I migrate the foreign key just dot get the user_id assigned. Thanks for helping me out stuck for few days now :(

Comment: Allright, usually when a field is not being filled, you might have a problem with the model `Article`(usually). I think you are using a seeder, which usually creates records by using mass-assignment(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment). I think you miss, or miss-spelled the `user_id` field in your `$fillables` array in your `Article` model. Could you verify?(maybe upload the model and seeder if it is not the case?) Another problem might be that the `users.id` does not exist when creating the `articles` record.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks done abit more digging and got suggestion on laracast website so if some one stuck try to do the following changes:
in your laravel /config/database.php file change the following:

```
'engine' => null, 
 //Change the null to InnoDB as bellow:
'engine' => InnoDB,
```